# c++ and matlab floating point computation

Tags: c++, matlab, floating-point

Could someone tell me if c++ and matlab use the same floating point computation implementations? Will I get the same values in C++ as I would in Matlab?

Currently I have these discrepancies from translating my Matlab code into C++:

```
Matlab: R = 1.0000000001623, I = -3.07178893432791e-010, C = -3.79693498864242e-011

C++:    R = 1.00000000340128 I = -3.96890964537988e-009  Z = 2.66864907949582e-009
```

If not what is the difference and where can I find more about floating point computation implementations?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that floating point is native to the processor, and not the language, but i'm not sure enough to write this in the answer box.

Comment: Never ever expect consistency with floating point calculations - even just changing the order can deliver different results, even if the same CPU instructions are used.

Comment: You might need to show some code, and not merely results, to elicit useful answers.

Comment: Matlab as well as c++ don't specify what fp standard to use. As far as I know matlab uses [MKL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) for some things and that in turn uses intel's extended format. Still I'm not sure why that'd be important.

Comment: Any time you want to compare the results of floating point computations that should come out the same, figure out an appropriate error tolerance, and test whether the answers are within that range of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not clear what your numbers actually are, the relative difference of the first (and largest) numbers is about 1e-8, which is the relative tolerance of many double precision algorithms.

Floating point numbers are only an approximation of the real number system, and their finite size (64 bits for double precision) limits their precision.  Because of this finite precision, operations that involve floating point numbers can incur round-off error, and are thus not strictly associative.  What this means is that A+(B+C) != (A+B)+C.  The difference between the two is usually small, depending on their relative sizes, but it's not always zero.

What this means is that you should expect small differences in the relative and absolute values when you compare an algorithm coded in Matlab to one in C++.  The difference may be in the libraries (i.e., there's no guarantee that Matlab uses the system math library for routines like `sqrt`), or it may just be that your C++ and Matlab implementations order their operations differently.

The section on [floating point comparison tests](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/floating_point_comparison.html) in Boost::Test discusses this a bit, and has some good references.  In particular, you should probably read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and consider picking up a copy of Knuth's [TAOCP Vol. II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896842).

Answer (score 0):

Matlab by default uses a double floating point precision, a C float uses a single floating point precision.

The representation for floating points is the same between the two, and is either processor or I believe a standard. But as mentioned, floating points are extremely fickle, you always have to allow for some tolerance. If you do a complex operation, such as the one below, you will frequently get a non-zero number, despite algebra telling you otherwise. The stuff under the hood between how operations are done with matlab and c will allow for some differences. Just make sure they are close.

```
((3*pi+2)*5-9)/2-7.5*pi-3
```